# Delay when playing sound

Tags: sound

In a script I play a sound ( `.ogg` file) using `/usr/bin/play`.  The sound is played fine, but there is an annoying delay of a couple of seconds after the sound has been played before the program (`play`) terminates.  Why is that, and can it be fixed?

The script is a git-commit hook.  It just calls p`lay -q filename.ogg`.  I have the same experience from the command line.

I'm on 10.04 if that’s relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to wait for the sound to be completed, right? So you could just

```
play file.ogg </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

(or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673119/detaching-a-process-from-terminal-entirely) for more intense detaching). Also try `ogg123` or `mplayer` instead of `play`, or try a different audio output.

Answer (score 0):

I would attribute that to the time it takes for the application to shut down. It really depends how you wrote the script.

This might be more of scripting issue than a ubuntu one.